# How to initialize a pointer to an array as a member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

I am trying to declare a member variable that is an array of unknown size, that contains pointers to objects (objects that don't have default constructors).  Additionally, I want the array to be populated with `NULL` pointers until I explicitly assign it.  How do I do this?

Here is what I have so far (unrelated code removed):

In the .h:

```
class Column
{
    private:

        Card  **_cards;
        qint32 _color;
};
```

In the .cpp:

```
Column::Column( qint32 color )
    :
_color( color )
{
    _cards = new Card[Card::maxValue()];
}
```

Here are the relevant compiler errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Card::Card()’
error: cannot convert ‘Card*’ to ‘Card**’ in assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
class Column
{
    private:
        Card **_cards;
        qint32 _color;
};

Column::Column( qint32 color )
    : _cards(new Card *[Card::maxValue()])
      _color( color )
{
    for (size_t i=0; i!=Card::maxValue(); ++i) {
        _cards[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

but of course, using a `std::vector` would be better:

```
class Column
{
    private:
        std::vector<Card *> _cards;
        qint32 _color;
};

Column::Column( qint32 color )
    : _cards(Card::maxValue(),0)
      _color( color )
{
}
```

Comment: Works great!  Thanks for giving both examples.  I'm still learning C++ and seeing both examples was excellent for learning.  Thanks!